# Why is @@@@P` is being added to char array after sorting

Tags: c++

I'm reading unsorted chars from input.txt using fstream, adding them to a[], sorting a[] and then putting a[] into output.txt. For some reason it always adds random chars like @@@@P` at the beginning of the output. Why is that?
Here's the code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
ifstream infile("input.txt");
    if(!infile){
        cout << "I cannot open the infile!\n";
        return 1;
    }
char a[100];
int c,d;
infile >> a >> c >> d;
int i,j,temp;
int l = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < l-1; j++){
            if(a[j+1] < a[j]){
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

for(int p = 0;p < l; p++){
   cout << a[p];
}
infile.close();

ofstream outfile("output.txt");

if(!outfile){
    cout << "I cannot open the outfile\n!";
    return 1;
}

for(int p = 0;p < l; p++){
   outfile << a[p];
}
infile.close();
return 0;
}
```

And input.txt

```
flohjenwxhas
```

Comment: You're sorting all 100 elements of `a`, even if the input is shorter than that. The rest of the array contains uninitialized characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
infile >> a >> c >> d;
```

requires a `char` array and 2 integers all separated by spaces.

```
flohjenwxhas
```

contains no spaces so the char array gobbles everything up and the stream read fails untested leaving nothing for `c` and `d`. This means `c` and `d` are used without being set later in the program. This be [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Crom only knows what crazy smurf will result when they are used.

```
int l = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
```

Computes the number of element in array `a`. Not only is this redundant, it will always be 100, it is far more than the number of characters in "flohjenwxhas". This has you sorting and swapping who-knows-what in the uninitialized portion of `a`.

You likely meant to use

```
int l = strlen(a);
```

But a vastly better approach is to make `a` a `std::string` and use `a.size()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the thing with the spaces. Honestly didn't know that was a factor. And you were right about strlen(),idk  how did I managed to forget it.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is 12 characters long, so:

```
cin >> a
```

will only fill in the first 13 characters of `a` -- 12 characters from the input, and 1 null byte. The rest of the array is uninitialized.

```
l = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
```

sets `l` to `100`, so you then sort all 100 elements of the array, not just the 12 input characters. `@@@@P` is just some of the garbage characters that happen to be in the uninitialized string.

Change it to:

```
l = strlen(a);
```

You'll need `#include <cstring>` to get this function.